# Remember window locations when docked and undocked

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I find this beyond frustrating.

I have two extra screens on my laptop at work. I take my laptop and go home, with no extra screens connected. I come back, dock the laptop, and the windows need to be rearranged again.

Is there a way to get windows (or a utility) to keep track of the overall screen configuration (#, size, resolution), and remember where windows were placed, so when the screen configuration matches again, it puts applications BACK where they were?

Comment: I run into the same issue but my complaint is when I open the laptop later and the application window is still off-screen (end up using the arrow keys to move it back onscreen). I don't think there is a built-in solution to this.

Answer (score 30):

DISCLAIMER: I'm the creator of this tool.

I've created a little tool to rearrange windows on a traybar icon click.
You may compile it from source or ask to have a (portable) binary through the issues link.

It is hosted at Github: https://github.com/manutalcual/winredock

I would be glad to hear from you if you have suggestions.

EDIT: 2018/11/22

It is fully automated now.

Comment: This looks nice but I am looking for something more automatic.

Comment: I've added the automation feature due to user requests.

Comment: Note that the version in Master has issues at least on Windows 10 with virtual desktops. Use the branch called [I0010-restoring-positions-doesnt-work](https://github.com/manutalcual/winredock/blob/I0010-restoring-positions-doesnt-work/bin/bin.zip)

Comment: I've merged branch I0010-restoring-positions-doesnt-work  into master, so now we may be working better

Comment: This is fantastic! It works super well on first try! Thank you for making this!

Comment: Tried this solution on 5/12/2020 and it worked great. Thank you for the application.

Comment: Very cool. I was getting tired of Win+M and then Win+Shift+M every time I wanted to switch systems.

Answer (score 12):

I'm currently using DisplayFusion Pro for window location (not only). I don't know how this works when you disconnect and connect your monitor - I have three always.

I think, that you must close and reopen your apps to be re-arranged.

Edit: This is feature is available only in Pro version. - Information from comments.

[image: screenshot of settings]

homepage of [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/)

Comment: FYI, the Window Location feature appears to solve my request. It should be noted to anyone else that this is a PRO version requiring a purchased license.

Comment: See the "Save or Restore all window locations" feature in the [Feature Comparison](https://www.displayfusion.com/Compare) for Free vs. Pro. Unfortunately the cheapest solution is $25.

Comment: Does this work when you have multiple native virtual desktops in Windows 10?

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a console application](https://github.com/pngan/winlayout) to save and restore window locations and states on a Windows Desktop.  To save windows locations run:

```
  winLayout save
```

to restore windows positions run:

```
  winLayout restore
```

Put these commands into a Desktop shortcut and pin to the Taskbar for convenience.

Disclaimer: I wrote this utility because the other tools on this page didn't work for me.

Caveat: It works for applications, but not explorer windows (at present)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Windows applications don't really see multiple monitors.  The window manager keeps track of window positions in reference to the Top-Left corner or your main display.  I'm not aware of any commercial applications that do, but you could write an application in C# or even VB.NET that could write these values to a file and restore them later, but there would be no "trigger" for it.  You'd have to tell the program when to store and retrieve the data manually.

Answer (score 2):

Try this script, written for Excel. It stores the window positions in a sheet and restores them from there. You may have buttons on one of the sheets to run the store and restore macros, or shortcuts to VBS scripts that run the Excel macros, maybe with shortcut keys assigned.  That way the Excel workbook can remain minimized. Of course something similar may be written in a compiled program.

```vb
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowPlacement Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, lpwndpl As WINDOWPLACEMENT) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPlacement Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, lpwndpl As WINDOWPLACEMENT) As Long
        
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
            
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Boolean
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As LongPtr) As Long
    
    Public Type POINTAPI
    X As Long
    Y As Long
    End Type
    
    Public Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
    End Type
    
    Public Type WINDOWPLACEMENT
    Length As Long
        flags As Long
        showCmd As Long
        MinPosition As POINTAPI
        MaxPosition As POINTAPI
        rcNormalPosition As RECT
    End Type
    
    Global Const gw_hwndnext = 2
    Global Const fwp_startswith = 0
    Global Const fwp_contains = 1
    Global title As String
    Global Visible As Boolean
    Global RowCount
    Public prog As String
    
    
    Public Sub StoreActiveWindows()
        Dim hwndapp As Long
        Dim hwndmax As Long
        Dim nret As Long
        Dim WinFrm As WINDOWPLACEMENT
        Dim RectFrm As RECT
        
        PleaseWait.Show vbModeless
        DoEvents
        
        RowCount = 1
        hwndmax = findwindow(0&, 0&)
        Do Until hwndmax = 0
        hwndapp = findthiswindow(hwndmax)
        If hwndapp Then
            If title <> "CURRENT WINDOWS OPEN" And Visible Then
                rtn = GetWindowPlacement(hwndapp, WinFrm)
            
                RectFrm = WinFrm.rcNormalPosition
        
                FrmTop = RectFrm.Top
                FrmRight = RectFrm.Right
                FrmLeft = RectFrm.Left
                FrmBottom = RectFrm.Bottom
                Workbooks(Filename).Activate
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 1) = title
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 2) = hwndapp
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 3) = FrmTop
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 4) = FrmRight
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 5) = FrmLeft
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 6) = FrmBottom
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 7) = WinFrm.MaxPosition.X
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 8) = WinFrm.MaxPosition.Y
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 9) = WinFrm.MinPosition.X
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 10) = WinFrm.MinPosition.Y
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 11) = WinFrm.showCmd
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 12) = WinFrm.flags
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 13) = WinFrm.Length
                RowCount = RowCount + 1
            End If
        End If
        hwndmax = GetWindow(hwndmax, gw_hwndnext)
        Loop
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 1) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 2) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 3) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 4) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 5) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 6) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 7) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 8) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 9) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 10) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 11) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 12) = ""
                Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 13) = ""
    
        Unload PleaseWait
    
    End Sub
    
    Public Function findthiswindow(ByVal hwndtopmost As Long) As Long
        Dim hwndtmp As Long
        Dim nret As Long
        Dim titletmp As String
    
        'Get the first window
        hwndtmp = hwndtopmost
        
        If GetParent(hwndtmp) = 0 Then
            'Set its visibility
            If IsWindowVisible(hwndtmp) Then
                Visible = True
            Else
                Visible = False
            End If
            'Get its title
            titletmp = Space(256)
            nret = GetWindowText(hwndtmp, titletmp, Len(titletmp))
            If nret Then
                findthiswindow = hwndtmp
            End If
        End If
    
        If Visible Then
            title = titletmp & " - Visible"
            Else
            title = titletmp & " - Invisible"
            End If
            title = titletmp
            If titletmp <> "" Then
            
            'If title = "SETTINGS" Then
                HasNoOWner = Not (GetWindow(hwndtmp, 4))
                n = 1
            'End If
            
            If (UCase(Left(title, 15)) = "PROGRAM MANAGER" Or UCase(title) = "SETTINGS") Then
                n = 1
                title = ""
                findthiswindow = 0
            End If
        End If
    End Function
    
    Sub RestoreWindowsLocations()
        Dim WinFrm As WINDOWPLACEMENT
        Dim RectFrm As RECT
        
        PleaseWait.Show vbModeless
        DoEvents
        
        Workbooks(Filename).Activate
        
        RowCount = 1
        Do Until Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 1) = ""
            hwndapp = Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 2)
    '       rtn = GetWindowPlacement(hwndapp, WinFrm)
            WinFrm.rcNormalPosition.Top = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 3))
            WinFrm.rcNormalPosition.Right = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 4))
            WinFrm.rcNormalPosition.Left = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 5))
            WinFrm.rcNormalPosition.Bottom = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 6))
            WinFrm.MaxPosition.X = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 7))
            WinFrm.MaxPosition.Y = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 8))
            WinFrm.MinPosition.X = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 9))
            WinFrm.MinPosition.Y = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 10))
            WinFrm.showCmd = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 11))
            WinFrm.flags = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 12))
            WinFrm.Length = CLng(Workbooks(Filename).Sheets("Active Windows").Cells(RowCount, 13))
            
            rtn = SetWindowPlacement(hwndapp, WinFrm)
            rtn = SetWindowPlacement(hwndapp, WinFrm)
            
            RowCount = RowCount + 1
        
        Loop
        Unload PleaseWait
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain what this is supposed to do and clean up and format the entire code block properly as it's hard to read as-is.

Comment: And can you explain how to have VBS scripts that run the Excel macros? How can something similar be written into a compiled program?

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Have you yourself uses it? I am sure a lot of people would benefit if you can create an end-to-end working sample

Answer (score 1):

A lot of windows users had this issue, an application was developed and shared within the windows 7 forums as shown here:

Link: http://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html#post396744

There are instructions on the site which help and it should fix your issue.

Comment: The forum says "This is an app to make Windows 7 explorer folder windows remember their size and position" and " It does NOT manage window size/positions of regular applications, if you want that, other apps like **Window Manager** do it".

What is meant by **Window Manager**? Is that the Microsoft Windows Manager service or the product from DeskSoft [link](http://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm)

Comment: yes it is the product from DeskSoft

Answer (score 1):

This one was looking promising: https://github.com/adamsmith/WindowsLayoutSnapshot

Unfortunately in my case, when saving the layout on 3x 24" 1920x1200 monitors, changing to one laptop 1920x1080, and then going back to three and trying to restore layout, windows didn't really move to other monitors. But maybe for someone else on other setup it will work.

Comment: Looks promising, but that won't run on my PC (Windows 8.1)

Comment: Discontinued unfortunately, and it loses all the config when the program is closed or the PC is restarted, which the author doesn't plan to fix.

Comment: The new version available here - https://github.com/nefarius/WindowsLayoutSnapshot . Works perfectly on win10!

Answer (score 1):

Windows 11 can remember window locations:

[image]

Related [Program to save visible windows' locations and later restore the layout](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1816/903).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with [Window Manager](https://www.desksoft.com/WindowManager.htm) from desksoft.com (there is a free trial period (the current price is $10)).

You configure two profiles (docked and undocked) and add a rule for each of the windows you want to place specifically. The profiles can be switched automatically via a "Screen Trigger".

I have a VNC session running full screen on one of two monitors but when I undock the laptop (e.g. to go to a meeting) I want to hide the VNC session without minimizing it. This can be done by moving it to a secondary Windows desktop.

I am not associated with DeskSoft in any way.

Answer (score -1):

I've used [Stardock’s Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) before in a similar scenario:

> Fences helps you organize your PC by automatically placing your
>   shortcuts and icons into resizable shaded areas on your desktop called
>   fences. Its many customization features are what make Fences the
>   world's most popular Windows desktop enhancement.

Comment: That arranges icons.  Not windows.  My issue is that I have 8 programs open across three screens.  When I close the laptop, and re-open it with the three screens all my application windows are open on one screen, not arranged how I had them.