# How to force Internet Explorer to keep its window size when being docked?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, desktop, aero-snap, docking

Using Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 8, the window size *is* being remembered, when the IE window is *not* docked/snapped to an edge.

As soon as I dock IE to one side of my screen, close it and reopen it, the window size set to something other (probably the size of the non-docked window?)

**Steps to show the behavior**

1.) Start Internet Explorer. It shows in its last window position

[image]

2.) Drag window with the mouse to one side (or use <kbd>[image: Windows]</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>). Internet Explorer is getting docked

[image]

3.) Close Internet Explorer

4.) Start Internet Explorer. It is being shown in its last *undocked* window position

[image]

**My question is**

How to force Internet Explorer remember its window position, even if it is docked?

**Update 2013-11-06:**

If there is no solution for for Internet Explorer, maybe there is a generic tool? A [similar SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/593701/remember-window-locations-when-docked-and-undocked) reveals no results, unfortunately.

Comment: After years of struggling with this "Feature", I found a nice, affordable tool today: "[DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/)". Among many other features, this tool provides the function to listen to events like an opening new window and then is able to position this window as configured. Works very well for me.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, Chrome's handling of this seems to be the one that is non-standard.

From what I can tell, most apps behave the same way that IE does, and I believe it's an intentional design decision. To be honest, I prefer the way IE handles it ... the "snapped" state of a window is not the same thing as it's normal state or it's maximized state.

I typically have my IE windows in a specific spot, set to a specific size, on my desktop. Occasionally, however, I want to snap a window so I can do some comparisons, etc. I don't want that snap behavior to change where I normally place my IE window or the size of it.

I understand that this doesn't fit with what *you* want, though. That's why making decisions about UX is so difficult. :)

Comment: "[Don't make me think](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_Make_Me_Think)" ;-)

Comment: To counter this: I use my browser maximized, and I like that it opens as I left it - maximized, or on the center of the screen, or... If I left it docked, I would expect it to reopen docked.

Answer (score 1):

IE 10 doesn't remember it's snapped position when you close it.

You can use a shortcut to quickly move it where you need to.

> Windows logo key [image: Picture] + Left Arrow or Right Arrow

Comment: Thanks, I know this shortcut. I just can't believe the Google Chrome does handle even those tiny little things waaaaaaay better than Microsoft itself with Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the built-in Windows shortcuts, use something like [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) to create your own shortcuts that actually resize the window, which IE (and other apps) will then remember. I personally use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 4</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 6</kbd>.

On Windows 7 and below, [WinSplit Revolution](http://download.cnet.com/WinSplit-Revolution/3000-2072_4-10971915.html) was good for this, but it's no longer supported - and I don't think the last version works on Windows 8. There are several [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/winsplit-revolution/) that might be worth looking at though.

Comment: Just found [MaxTo](https://maxto.net/) via Google. 19 USD. Maybe a good alternative.

Answer (score -2):

The key piece that everyone misses with this is that they actually need to do File Close after resizing to appropriate size and not click on the red x or any other method of closing out Internet Explorer.  If this step is not followed the screen size/location is not saved or updated.  In newer versions of Internet Explorer you need to press the Alt key on your keyboard before the file menu will even appear on Internet Explorer with default settings.

Comment: I've just tried this and I cannot confirm your answer. This did not work for me at all.

Comment: File-Close is not so necessary as this answer claims.